# Anime.js - элементы анимации с различной продолжительностью

Tags: javascript, анимация, anime.js

Имеется html-элемент, который нужно бесконечно вращать, но передвинуть только 1 раз. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью вызова anime.js 2 раза.

В таком варианте не работает смещение, но работает вращение.

```js
anime({
  targets: '.element',
  translateX: [200,0],
  translateY: [100,0],
  opacity: [0,1],
  delay: 3500,
  duration: 1200,
  easing: 'easeOutQuad'
});
anime({
  targets: '.element',
  rotate: '1turn',
  duration: 4000,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear'
});
```

Если вызовы поменять местами, то в целом работает, но идет перескакивание во вращении после смещения.

----------UPDATE----------

Действительно, если поменять местами вызовы и сложить delay + duration = duration: 4700, то не всё работает и не происходит перескока в анимации, но почему именно этот вариант работает, а первый нет, совершенно непонятно.

```js
anime({
  targets: '.element',
  rotate: '1turn',
  duration: 4700,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear'
});
anime({
  targets: '.element',
  translateX: [200,0],
  translateY: [100,0],
  opacity: [0,1],
  delay: 3500,
  duration: 1200,
  easing: 'easeOutQuad'
});
```

Comment: в 2 дива раскинуть ? один див один раз сдвинуть, внутренний зациклить и крутить

Comment: А в чем смысл - один придется как-то убирать, чтобы второй точно такой же потом крутился на месте?

Comment: я предположил ) не работал с Anime.js , подождем, может оттветит тот у кого есть понимание как оно внутри там )

Answer (score 1):

Для запуска анимаций друг за другом в фреймворке `animejs` используется: [Timeline](https://animejs.com/documentation/#timelineBasics)

> Временные шкалы позволяют синхронизировать несколько анимаций вместе.
> По умолчанию каждая анимация, добавляемая на шкалу времени, начинается
> после окончания предыдущей.

Создание `Timeline`

```
const timeline = anime.timeline({
   autoplay: true,
  loop:true,
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
});
```

Далее с помощью метода `.add` добавляются анимации вращения и перемещения объекта:

```js
const timeline = anime.timeline({
   autoplay: true,
  loop:true,
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
});

timeline.add({
  targets: '.element',
  rotate: '3turn',
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 2000,
  
})
.add({
  targets: '.element',
  translateX: [0, 200],
  translateY: [0, 200],
   opacity:[1,0.2],
   duration: 2000,
});
```

```css
.element {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:yellowgreen;
margin:4em;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```

*Вариант с возвратом объекта и зацикливанием*

```js
const timeline = anime.timeline({
   autoplay: true,
  loop:true,
  easing: 'easeInOutSine',
});

timeline.add({
  targets: '.element',
  rotate: '3turn',
  easing: 'linear',
  duration: 3000,
  
})
.add({
  targets: '.element',
  translateX: [0, 200, 0],
  translateY: [0, 200, 0],
   opacity:[1,0.2,1],
   duration: 2000,
});
```

```css
.element {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:yellowgreen;
margin:4em;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
<div class="element"></div>
```